# How do I marshall nested key,value pairs into JSON with Camel and Jackson library?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, apache-camel

I have a Java project that currently returns a map to Camel without any nested key,value pairs, and the Jackson library marshalls it just fine into JSON using the Jackson library.

For example if I put the following two key,values into a demoMap:

```
Map<String,String> demoMap = new TreeMap<String,String>
demoMap.put("key1","5");
demoMap.put("key2","10");
```

I get the following JSON:

```
{"key1":"5","key2":"10"}
```

However, now some of my key,value entries will have an optional visibility that I need to put as a nested key value in my map.  Any key,values that don't have an optional visibility will use the default.  So, for example if I specify visibilities for key1, and key2, but not key3 I want to get JSON out that looks like this:

```
{"key1":"5",
 "key2":"10",
 "key3":"17",
 "visibility" : { "key1": "a&b&!c", "key2": "a&b", "_default": "a" }
}
```

How can I get Camel to marshall a Java object with nested key,value pairs?  I'm a visual learner, so a simple example would be helpful.

I tried changing my Map to have a value as an object i.e.,:

```
Map<String,Object> demoMap = new TreeMap<String,Object>
```

and then tried adding nested key,values for some keys with an ArrayList using http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/json/jackson/convert-java-map-to-from-json-using-jackson-example/ for reference, but realized that this just gives me a bunch of nested values under a key, not a bunch of nested key,value pairs.

Even when I tried it for grins, I got an error from the Camel processor with a java.lang.ClassCastException stating java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String

And similarly when I tried to nest a Map inside my demoMap I got this ClassCastException:

```
3244 [hello.world.request.timer] ERROR org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler  - Failed delivery for exchangeId: e6518e39-89b7-435e-96d9-ce26811ac67e. Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

So I know how NOT to do it. :-/

I re-read the Camel JSON documentation at http://camel.apache.org/json.html but as of this writing it doesn't specify an example with nested key,value pairs.

UPDATE: Based on feedback from Tom I created two Maps i.e.,

```
Map<String,String> keyvalues = new TreeMap<String,String>();
Map<String,String> visibility = new TreeMap<String,String>();
```

Here is my class which I call SensorGenerator that loads a properties file into a Map:

```
package sample;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAnyGetter;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;

public class SensorGenerator {

    private Properties sourceProperties;

    // create a map of sensor keyvalues, and a map of sensor visibility
    Map<String,String> keyvalues = new TreeMap<String,String>();
    @JsonProperty
    Map<String,String> visibility = new TreeMap<String,String>();

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, String> getKeyvalues() { 

        for (Object key : sourceProperties.keySet()) {

            // Separate out each of the field:datatype:visibility tuples as an entry in the
            // values array
            String[] values = sourceProperties.getProperty((String) key).split(
                    ",");
            // split the key between 'sensor' and the 'number' Ex: sensor1 -> sensor,1
            String[] keyArray = key.toString().split("(?<=([a-zA-Z]++))");
            String keyNumber = keyArray[1]; // grab the number to append for each sensor

            // define string buffer that appends sensor number for each sensor's
            // keys.  Ex: sensor1 would have s1make, s1makeDataType, etc.
            StringBuffer sensorNumberStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            sensorNumberStringBuffer.append("s");
            sensorNumberStringBuffer.append(keyNumber);

            // make, its data type, and visibility (with s# prefix)
            StringBuffer makeStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            makeStringBuffer.append(sensorNumberStringBuffer);
            makeStringBuffer.append("make");
            StringBuffer makeDataTypeStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            makeDataTypeStringBuffer.append(sensorNumberStringBuffer);
            makeDataTypeStringBuffer.append("makeDataType");
            StringBuffer makeVizStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            makeVizStringBuffer.append(sensorNumberStringBuffer);
            makeVizStringBuffer.append("makeViz");

            // model, its data type, and visibility (with s# prefix)
            StringBuffer modelStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            modelStringBuffer.append(sensorNumberStringBuffer);
            modelStringBuffer.append("model");
            StringBuffer modelDataTypeStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            modelDataTypeStringBuffer.append(sensorNumberStringBuffer);
            modelDataTypeStringBuffer.append("modelDataType");
            StringBuffer modelVizStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            modelVizStringBuffer.append(sensorNumberStringBuffer);
            modelVizStringBuffer.append("modelViz");

            // serialNumber, its data type, and visibility (with s# prefix)
            StringBuffer serialNumberStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            serialNumberStringBuffer.append(sensorNumberStringBuffer);
            serialNumberStringBuffer.append("serialNumber");
            StringBuffer serialNumberDataTypeStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            serialNumberDataTypeStringBuffer.append(sensorNumberStringBuffer);
            serialNumberDataTypeStringBuffer.append("serialNumberDataType");
            StringBuffer serialNumberVizStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            serialNumberVizStringBuffer.append(sensorNumberStringBuffer);
            serialNumberVizStringBuffer.append("serialNumberViz");

            // sensorType, its data type, and visibility (with s# prefix)
            StringBuffer sensorTypeStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            sensorTypeStringBuffer.append(sensorNumberStringBuffer);
            sensorTypeStringBuffer.append("sensorType");
            StringBuffer sensorTypeDataTypeStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            sensorTypeDataTypeStringBuffer.append(sensorNumberStringBuffer);
            sensorTypeDataTypeStringBuffer.append("sensorTypeDataType");
            StringBuffer sensorTypeVizStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            sensorTypeVizStringBuffer.append(sensorNumberStringBuffer);
            sensorTypeVizStringBuffer.append("sensorTypeViz");

            //  put all the field:datatype keyvalues for this sensor in the keyvalues map
            //  and visibilities in the visibility map

            // make, data type, and visibility
            keyvalues.put(makeStringBuffer.toString(), values[0].split(":")[0]);
            keyvalues.put(makeDataTypeStringBuffer.toString(), values[0].split(":")[1]);
            visibility.put(makeVizStringBuffer.toString(), values[0].split(":")[2]);

            // model, data type, and visibility
            keyvalues.put(modelStringBuffer.toString(), values[1].split(":")[0]);
            keyvalues.put(modelDataTypeStringBuffer.toString(), values[1].split(":")[1]);
            visibility.put(modelVizStringBuffer.toString(), values[1].split(":")[2]);

            // serialNumber, data type, and visibility
            keyvalues.put(serialNumberStringBuffer.toString(), values[2].split(":")[0]);
            keyvalues.put(serialNumberDataTypeStringBuffer.toString(), values[2].split(":")[1]);
            visibility.put(serialNumberVizStringBuffer.toString(), values[2].split(":")[2]);

            // sensorType, data type, and visibility
            keyvalues.put(sensorTypeStringBuffer.toString(), values[3].split(":")[0]);
            keyvalues.put(sensorTypeDataTypeStringBuffer.toString(), values[3].split(":")[1]);
            visibility.put(sensorTypeVizStringBuffer.toString(), values[3].split(":")[2]);

            // add in default visibility
            visibility.put("_default", "a");

        }
        return keyvalues;
    }

    public void setSourceProperties(Properties properties) {
        this.sourceProperties = properties;
    }

}
```

Right now I just hardcoded the default visibility to "a", but will change that later to also be pulled from a properties file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your structure is a more than a map.  It's two maps that are serialised differently.  One way to represent this is:

```
public class Whatever{
  Map<String,String> keyvalues;
  Map<String,String> visibility;
}
```

What you'll end up with is this, which although represents the data is far from ideal:

```
{
 "keyvalues" : { "key1": "5", "key2": "10", "key3": "17"},
 "visibility" : { "key1": "a&b&!c", "key2": "a&b", "_default": "a" }
}
```

To get what you want, use @JsonAnyGetter.  Something like this (it could be made much easier to use):

```
public class Whatever{
    Map<String,String> keyvalues = new TreeMap<String,String>();
    @JsonProperty
    Map<String,String> visibility = new TreeMap<String,String>();

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, String> getKeyvalues() {
        return keyvalues;
    }
}
```

which produces:

```
           {"visibility":{"key1":"a&b&!c","key2":"a&b"},"key1":"5","key2":"10"}
```

I've been battling this today and your question inspired me to make it bloody work :D  The annotations are here: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations

See JUnit test here: https://gist.github.com/TomDemeranville/7009250

Comment: Tom, thank you for the information.  I added in the code you suggested, but when I run the program I only see the keyvalues in the JSON.  For some reason I don't see the nested visibility fields.  I'll attach my SensorGenerator.java class, perhaps I'm missing something :-)

Comment: here it is as a JUnit test.  This test works for me.  What version Jackson are you using?  https://gist.github.com/TomDemeranville/7009250

Comment: I'm using camel-jackson 2.12.1.  I have the following dependency in my pom.xml:     <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
   <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
   <version>${camel}</version>
  </dependency>     where I define ${camel} above as 2.12.1

Comment: I just noticed that I'm using different libraries that you are for JsonAnyGetter and JsonProperty.  You are using:  import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;  and I'm using import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAnyGetter;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;  Did you specify the com.fasterxml library in your pom.xml?

Comment: You are using an old version.  The new version uses the fasterxml namespace.  I'm using Jackson 2.2.3 I think.  You may have both versions on your classpath.

Comment: Are you specifying that newer version in your pom.xml or your applicationContext.xml?  I looked in both and I don't seem to specify a version for the Jackson library.  I guess that's why its using an older version.

Comment: Here's all I've currently specified in my applicationContext.xml for marshalling to JSON:                                             <!-- Add Jackson library to render Java Map into JSON -->
     <camel:dataFormats>
          <camel:json id="jack" library="Jackson"/>
        </camel:dataFormats>

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml and Camel applicationContext.xml files with your JUnit test?  I want to see if I can figure out what to add to call the newer Jackson library.  Thanks.

Comment: Btw, I looked under my .classpath under my Eclipse project and found out that yes, I am specifying multiple versions of the Jackson library, i.e.:   <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-asl/0.9.4/jackson-asl-0.9.4.jar"/>

Comment: And then further down in my .classpath I have:         <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/home/accumulo/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.8.8/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar">  with a bunch of attributes set

Comment: Mine is imported as a dependency of restlet 2.2-M3.

Comment: I'm also using   <dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency> which seems to be importing it as well.  Part of my jackson is 2.1, other parts 2.2.3.  Doh.

Comment: I couldn't seem to get maven to pull down the fasterxml.jackson.library, so I downloaded the jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar and added it to my classpath.  It now points my SensorGenerator class to the same library as yours, but I still don't get the nested visibility

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I discovered some Jackson library conflicts in my pom.xml that I'm cleaning up.