# Does camel-jackson 2.12.1 support marshalling of nested objects into nested JSON?

Tags: json, list, jackson, apache-camel

I have the following two Java classes (SensorData, and Visibility) to store dummy sensor data, and their respective visibilities into two objects:

## SensorData.java

```
package com.data.world2; 

import java.util.Map; 
import java.util.TreeMap; 

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter; 
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter; 
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty; 

public class SensorData { 

    private final Map<String, Object> keyvalues = new TreeMap<String, Object>(); 

    @JsonProperty 
    private Visibility visibility; 

    // getters and setters 
    @JsonAnyGetter 
    public Map<String, Object> getKeyvalues() { 
      return keyvalues; 
    } 

    @JsonAnySetter 
    public void setKeyvalues(final String key, final Object value) { 
      this.keyvalues.put(key, value); 
    } 

    // getters and setters 
    public Visibility getVisibility() { 
       return visibility; 
    } 

    public void setVisibility(Visibility visibility) { 
       this.visibility = visibility; 
    } 

}
```

## Visibility.java

```
package com.data.world2; 

import java.util.Map; 
import java.util.TreeMap; 

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter; 
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter; 

public class Visibility { 

    private final Map<String, Object> keyvalues = new TreeMap<String, Object>(); 

    // getters and setters 

    @JsonAnyGetter 
    public Map<String, Object> getKeyvalues() { 
       return keyvalues; 
    } 

    @JsonAnySetter 
    public void setKeyvalues(final String key, final Object value) { 
       this.keyvalues.put(key, value); 
    } 

}
```

And in my SensorGenerator class I store SensorData and Visibility keyvalue objects.  For example, suppose I have two keyvalue pairs from a sensor (make and model), and only the "make" keyvalue pair has a visibility specified; the "model" keyvalue pair uses the default visibility:

```
    // create a sensorData object, and a visibility object 
    SensorData sensorData = new SensorData(); 
    Visibility visibility = new Visibility(); 

    sensorData.setKeyValues("s1make", "Apple"); // set sensor 1 make 
    visibility.setKeyValues("s1make", "public"); // set sensor 1 make visibility 
    sensorData.setKeyValues("s1model", "iPhone5"); // set sensor 1 model 
    // sensor 1 model visibility not specified 

    // set default visibility 
    visibility.setKeyValues("_default", "private"); // set default visibility for sensor keyvalue pairs
```

Then I added the Visibility object to the SensorData object to get nested visibilities:

```
    // add the visibility to the SensorData object 
    sensorData.setVisibility(visibility);
```

## UPDATED:

The issue was that I was not returning the list back to Camel correctly for marshalling to JSON.

When I changed my code to the following I had the full nested JSON marshalled:

```
 List<SensorData> sensorDataList = new ArrayList<SensorData>();
 sensorDataList.add(sensorData);
```

The following is the previous way I had which was incorrect (just here for historical info)

And then I return a List of SensorData objects to my Camel thread for marshalling to JSON with the Jackson library (camel-jackson):

```
    // Build a sensorDataList based on the keyvalues stored in the SensorData object 
    List<SensorData> sensorDataList = new ArrayList(sensorData.getKeyvalues().entrySet());
```

When I run my Java program I'd expect to see the following nested JSON from my Camel route:

```
[{"key":"s1make","value":Apple"}, 
 {"key":"s1model","value":"iPhone5"}, 
 {"visibility": {"key":"s1make","value":"public", 
                 "key":"_default","value":"private"} 
}]
```

But instead, I only see are the SensorData keyvalues marshalled into JSON i.e.,:

```
[{"key":"s1make","value":Apple"}, 
 {"key":"s1model","value":"iPhone5"}]
```

How come I don't see the "s1make" and "_default" visibilities as nested JSON?  Does camel-jackson 2.12.1 not support marshalling of nested objects into nested JSON?

Btw, here is a snippet of my applicationContext.xml where I specify the marshalling to JSON:

```
      <camel:dataFormats>
         <camel:json id="jack" library="Jackson"/>
      </camel:dataFormats>

      <camel:route>

             <camel:from 
                     uri="timer://hello.world.request.timer?fixedRate=true&amp;period={{config.timeout}}" />
             <camel:to uri="log:hello.world.request?level=INFO&amp;showAll=true" />
             <camel:bean ref="helloWorld" />


             <camel:marshal ref ="jack"/>
             <camel:convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />
             <camel:log message="${body}"/>  


             <camel:log message="printing values read from config.properties file"/>
             <camel:log message="config.timeout= {{config.timeout}}"/>  
             <camel:log message="config.numSamples= {{config.numSamples}}"/>
             <camel:log message="config.defaultViz= {{config.defaultViz}}"/>


             <camel:to uri="log:hello.world.response?level=INFO&amp;showAll=true" />

       </camel:route>

 </camel:camelContext>
```

Last week I posted a similar question on SO, but realized after I posted it that I had to change my implementation to return a list to Camel instead of a map. 
[How do I marshall nested key,value pairs into JSON with Camel and Jackson library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389696/how-do-i-marshall-nested-key-value-pairs-into-json-with-camel-and-jackson-librar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you need to use `@JsonAnySetter/@JsonAnyGetter`, but if you must, try this in both classes

```
@JsonAnySetter 
public void add(String key, String value) {
      keyValues.put(key, value);
}
```

Meanwhile, your `setKeyValues` should take a `Map` parameter. As you have it now, you have stretched JavaBean conventions.

Also, take Camel out of the equation. Write unit tests to test your configuration and make sure your objects are serialized/deserialized as you expect before integrating them into Camel and waiting until runtime for things to blow up.

Comment: But, my keyvalues in both Java classes are a Map.  And things aren't blowing up with Camel, I'm just not getting all the data out into JSON.

Comment: I don't understand your first point. And by blowing up, I mean not working. I guess I am an alarmist haha. My point is that this has nothing to do with Camel; test outside the container. That's just good practice in general, and in this case it reduces your build/test/deploy cycle.

Comment: Well I'm confused how I'm violating JavaBean conventions when I am writing values to a map.  I in fact did test this code outside of Camel first.  I'm a big fan of incremental builds, and have actually done small increments up to this point.  This helloworld project is just a small test bed for us to test with Camel.  It is such a simple thing to write to a map, and then read it back as a list.  It seems that marshalling this to JSON with camel-jackson that should just work.

Comment: I didn't mean to challenge your process. So you're telling me if you just use plain Jackson in a unit test or a `main` method, then everything works as expected? If that's so, then you want to make sure camel-jackson has a dependency on the Jackson version you tested with...and that they can work together.

Comment: As for the JavaBean thing, `@JsonProperty` isn't the same as `@JsonAnySetter`, and I am pretty sure they expect different things. Check this out: http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_458.html

Comment: Actually adding the marshalling of the data to JSON is a new thing.  That's a good idea.  One thing I'm going to try before that though, is print out the full list and make sure the nested visbility values are truly in there.

Comment: so I figured out that I was not storing the object correctly into the Arraylist.  Therefore Jackson never saw my nested visibilities.  When I printed out the number of elements in my list I discovered my issue.  I'll update my list returned from my SensorGenerator class that is marshalled to nested JSON. :-)

Comment: Congratulations! I figured this had nothing to do with Camel or its integration with Jackson. As I said, it is important to make sure everything is working at its core before adding abstraction layers on top.

Comment: Yes, it was a simple case of Garbage In -> Garbage Out.  Once I realized my list didn't have my visibilities I couldn't blame Jackson since it only marshalls what is has.

Comment: So can a brother get an upvote for the second half of my answer? Haha